# Using local storage to allow someone to comment and then to show saved comments

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

Some elements of the different scripts are working but I cannot seem to get the saved comments to appear at the bottom of the page. Any suggestions as why some parts aren't working? When someone writes there name and in the text box and I press clear it clears the said fields, but I cannot get the comments saved and then displayed on the page. What have I done wrong?

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-
  8" />
  <title>Matthew comments</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" type="text/css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="myScript.js"></script>

  <script>
  function clearComment(){
  $('#txt1').val('');
  };

  </script>

  <script>
  function saveComment()
  var ctext = $('#txt1').val() 
  var cname = $('#namebox').val()
  if (cname === 'Name'){cname = 'Anon';
  alert(‘saveComment cname=’+cname+’ ctext=’+ctext)
  };

  </script>

  <script>

  var cmtlist = ‘<p><span class=”cmtname”’+cname+
  </span>'+ctext+’</p>’;
  $(‘#cmtlist’).empty();
  $(‘#cmtlist’).append(cmtlist);

  </script>

  <script type=”text/javascript”>
  // utility functions for localstorage
  function setObject(key, value) {
  window.localStorage.setItem(key,
  JSON.stringify(value));
  };
  function getObject(key) {
  var storage = window.localStorage;
  var value = storage.getItem(key);
  return value && JSON.parse(value);
  };
  function clearStorage() {
  // removes everything placed in localstorage
  window.localStorage.clear();
  };
  </script>

  <script>
  var cmtlist = $('#cmtlist').html();
  cmtlist = ‘<p><span class=”cmtname”’+cname+
  ‘</span >’+ctext+’</p>’+cmtlist;
  setObject('cmtlist', cmtlist);
  var cmtlist = getObject('cmtlist');
  if (getObject('cmtlist') === null){
  var cmtlist = '';
  } else {
  var cmtlist = getObject('cmtlist');
  };
  if ($('#txt1').val() === 'CLEAR ALL STORAGE NOW!'){
  clearStorage();
  };
  </script>

  </head>
  <body>
  <header id="banner">
  <dl>
  <dt>Matthew Wilson</dt><dd>
  <imgsrc="http://www.uea.ac.uk/documents/2397319/2396777/UEA+logo/bc91b5b5-ab8e-4673-b1e6-1a4a9fd918ab?t=1359129534719" alt="sloth" /></dd>
  </dl>
  </header>
  <nav>

  <button class="navbutton" onClick="clearComment()">Clear Comment</button>
  <button class="navbutton" onClick="saveComment()">Save Comment </button>

  </nav>
  <div id="main">


  <div id="dtext">
   <h4>Your comment</h4>
   <input id="namebox" type="text" maxlength="32" size="20"
   value="Name" />
  <br />
  <textarea id="txt1" class="textbox" rows="6"></textarea>


  </div>


   <h4>Comments</h4>
  <div id="cmtlist">



  </div>









     </div>
    </body>
     </html>
```

Comment: There are several things I think you should take a look first. Why are you defining SO MANY `script` tags? Why don't just put all your code inside one tag? And your `saveComment` function, it doesn't have the curly braces. You sure that is working as you expect?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

## html

```
<button class="navbutton" onClick="clearComment()">Clear Comment</button>
<button class="navbutton" onClick="saveComment()">Save Comment </button>

<div id="dtext">
  <h4>Your comment</h4>
  <input id="namebox" type="text" maxlength="32" size="20" placeholder="Name" />
  <br />
  <textarea id="txt1" class="textbox" rows="6" placeholder="Your comment"></textarea>
</div>

<h4>Comments</h4>
<div id="cmtlist"></div>
```

## javascript

```
// utility functions for localstorage
function setObject(key, value) {
  window.localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
}
function getObject(key) {
  var storage = window.localStorage,
      value = storage.getItem(key);
  return value && JSON.parse(value);
}
function clearStorage() {
  window.localStorage.clear();
}

// Clear inputfields and localstorage
function clearComment(){
  $('#txt1').val('');
  $('#namebox').val('');
  clearStorage();
}

function saveComment(){
  var cText = $('#txt1').val(),
      cName = $('#namebox').val(),
      cmtList = getObject('cmtlist');

  if (cmtList){
    cmtList.push({name: cName, text: cText});
    setObject('cmtlist', cmtList);
  }else{ //Add a comment
    setObject('cmtlist', [{name: cName, text: cText}]);
  }

  bindCmt();
}

function bindCmt(){
  var cmtListElement = $('#cmtlist'),
      cmtList = getObject('cmtlist');

  //Out with the old
  cmtListElement.empty();
  //And in with the new
  $.each(cmtList, function(i, k){
    cmtListElement.append( $('<p><span>'+ k.name +'</span>'+ k.text +'</p>') );
  });
}

//Get the comments on page ready
$(function(){
  bindCmt();
});
```